# destroy jQuery plugin instance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I've got a jQuery plugin that starts a `setInterval` when initialized on an element; something like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options){
        /* snip */
        var interval = setInterval(recurringFunction, options.interval);
        /* snip */
    };
})(jQuery);
```

I'd like to be able to do the general equivalent of jQuery UI's `.destroy()` function, where my plugin would clean up after itself and restore its target element (*without* removing it) to its original state (in my case, stopping that timeout). However, plain jQuery doesn't seem to have any standard convention for defining something like this. I **don't** use, need, or want jQuery UI. Is there a convention for cleaning up after a jQuery plugin, or do I just need to roll my own?

To clarify: I'm looking for a generic, common convention to define logic that cleans up after a plugin; I'm *not* asking how to clear a timeout.

Comment: _"destroy jQuery plugin instance"_, _"Is there a convention for cleaning up after a jQuery plugin?"_ and _"I'm looking for a generic, common convention to define logic that cleans up after a plugin"_ ~ AFAIK, there is no such thing.  In other words, each plugin may or may not provide a method for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to roll your own destroy method unless you are using the `jQueryUI` widget factory.